# Abstract type not valid in Exchange web services FindItem request

Tags: wsdl, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to use EWS to search a Task folder on Exchange 2010. I'm trying to limit the due dates of the Tasks returned, but unfortunately there's no equivalent to the CalendarView for the Task folder, so I have to use a FindItem search.

I'm using Java, Axis2 and I prepare the query like this:

```
// fiType is, obviously, a FindItemType  
RestrictionType rType = fiType.addNewRestriction();

IsGreaterThanOrEqualToType igtoretType = IsGreaterThanOrEqualToType.Factory.newInstance();  
igtoretType.addNewFieldURI().setFieldURI(UnindexedFieldURIType.TASK_DUE_DATE);  
igtoretType.addNewFieldURIOrConstant().addNewConstant().setValue(dateFormat.format(begCal.getTime()));  

IsLessThanOrEqualToType iltoretType = IsLessThanOrEqualToType.Factory.newInstance();  
iltoretType.addNewFieldURI().setFieldURI(UnindexedFieldURIType.TASK_DUE_DATE);  
iltoretType.addNewFieldURIOrConstant().addNewConstant().setValue(dateFormat.format(endCal.getTime()));  

SearchExpressionType[] seArr = new SearchExpressionType[2];  
seArr[0] = igtoretType;  
seArr[1] = iltoretType;  
AndType aType = rType.addNewAnd();  
aType.setSearchExpressionArray(seArr);
```

Unfortunately, I get this error:

> org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: La demande a échoué lors de la validation du schéma : L'élément 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types:SearchExpression' est abstrait ou son type l'est.

Roughly translated from French, it means that the query failed because the type SearchExpression is abstract, or it's type is.

After searching, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341126) article explaining how to modify the `types.xsd` file to take care of this. However, even after applying the modifications, I still get the same error.

I'm at a loss as to how to go about solving this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is [EWS Java API](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ewsjavaapi) by Microsoft...